# How to remove incorrectly escaped line breaks from a string

Tags: php, str-replace

Here I have a string, which at some point had its \r\n's improperly escaped.. We can't fundamentally fix this (imagine it comes from a different system).

```
$orig = 'Helprn rnrnI need somebodyrnrnrnHelp rnrnNo just burn baby burn anybody';
```

How could I safely, consistently replace rn's, but *not* alter words like bu**rn** (or any other word ending in rn e.g. http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/rn/)?

```
$correctString = str_replace(' rn', '<br/>', $orig);
$correctString = str_replace('<br/>rn', '<br/><br/>', $correctString);
// etc... until we have a totally clean string..
```

`$correctString` would have to end up looking like:

```
Help


I need somebody


Help 

No just burn baby burn anybody
```

Comment: Replacing the correct instances of `rn` with a `<br/>` isn't exactly what I would do. It's not really a carriage return, but a line break in HTML. What if you want to have this text reflow differently? Just a thought.

Comment: Are these strings in any (human) Language you have a complete dictionary of?

Comment: @EugenRieck, I would love to not have to loop through a dictionary, but I can't really think of any other way to accomplish this

Comment: I can't see a way without querying a dictionary for those words, that contain 'rn' - the information, wether 'rn' is part of the text or an artifact is basically lost, so we have to get it (rejoin it) from somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically impossible, some information was lost, so you won't be able to recreate it.

Only a manual post-processing will be able to distinguish exceptions like "burn".

I would say, if your text is always plain English, create a dictionnary of words containing "rn" and use them as exceptions in your algorithm, that would improve the process as it would work for "burn", but wouldn't be perfect as it wouldn't work for "burnrnbaby".

Answer (score 2):

I know of no method to detect "rn" properly as a carriage return when you have the situation posed in the question.

I think you would need to iterate over the text, broken up by whitespace, and compare each value to a dictionary.

But even that may prove impossible. What about words that contain "rn" but are *also* words (or names!) without the "rn"? How do you know whether the "rn" is a carriage return or part of the word?

> Learn wrote to her father. (Lea`<br/>` wrote to her father.)
>
> The paper was written torn address him. (The paper was written to`<br/>` address him.)

I think the only thing you can do safely is convert instances of "rnrn" to a double carriage return; as far as I know that pattern is not part of any word.

After that step, consider having the data converted by humans. But obviously the feasibility of such depends on the amount of data and availability of humans under your command (or checkbook...).

Answer (score 1):

If it is always groups of rn, like rnrnrn or rnrn then a regular expression for rn followed by one or more rn e.g.  (rn)\1+  to do a replace would work to some extent